# Dynamically add strings from array content

Tags: java, android

I have an array, which may differ in content based on some user selections.
One of the arrays look like this:

```
String[] get_elements = { "firstname", "lastname", "address", "status" };
```

In a static function, to get what I need to end up with, I would do this:

```
String name = c.getString(JSON_NAME);
String address = c.getString(JSON_ADDRESS);
String status = c.getString(JSON_STATUS);
```

Now, what I want to do, is set a string, based on what the content of the array is, like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < get_elements.length; x++) {
    String get_elements[x] = c.getString(get_elements[x]);
}
```

The array consists of: firstname, lastname, address and status.
So i want to end up with a loop-defining them as strings and assigning values to those strings, ending up with rawcode:

```
string firstname = c.getString("firstname");
```

And so on. I've tried using String get_elements[x] = c.getString(get_elements[x]) with no luck.
Is there a way to dynamically create strings based on the array content?

Comment: You can't have variables with dynamic names. Full stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't. The way you tried with array is the something you can try similar to this.

```
String[] elements=new String[4];
for (int x = 0; x < get_elements.length; x++) {
     elements[x] = c.getString(get_elements[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the existing element in array. Instead try this:

```
String result_elements = new String[get_elements.length];

for (int x = 0; x < get_elements.length; x++) {
    result_elements[x] = c.getString(get_elements[x]);
}
```

Hope it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot build an execute new java code at runtime. Besides, what would be the point of a single `String firstname` that contains `c.getString("firstname")` without any further information? You are better to use `c.getString("firstname")` where you need that sole return value.

You have to posses information about what data corresponds to what index. Take the name `"Carter"` as an example in addition to the fact, that the number of indices in the array may vary based on the user's choice. How are you going to examine, if `"Carter"` is the firstname or the lastname?